# How to bring popup to foreground?

Tags: abap, alv

I have a dynpro which creates a popup ALV (using a dialog container). A button on the popup will display another popup in the same way. My problem is that the last popup goes into the background, the selection going back to the first popup. Is there any way to fix/control this?

Comment: Hide the current popup, then show it again when the second popup is closed?

Comment: There is more than just one way to create a popup in ABAP. Can you show us a code example which reproduces the problem?